Orchestrated vs Core use-cases in clean architecture
I have an endpoint that should create a book, and if it is the clients first created book it should send an email like "Congratulations to your first book". Following Clean Architecture I thought I would create a CreateBookUseCase that both creates the book and sends the email. But I realised that does not really make sense, because now the use-case does more than it should, and also I dont want to send this email if another use-case creates a book as a side-effect, I only want to send the email if the action of creating a book has been sent from the client in this case. So how would I in Clean Architecture differ between a core use-case such as CreateBookUseCase that could potentially be reused, and a use-case that is orchestrated from multiple use-cases?
I was thinking about ways to differ between these two. Maybe call the orchestrated one CreateBookWorkflowUseCase or maybe have another type of use-cases I call Facades, which essentially is the outer use-cases used by other parts like the client, either through an api or something like a cli. So it could be CreateBookFacade. I also thought about something like HandleCreateBookActionUseCase to make it clear that the use-case is not made to "create a book", rather it handles when someone from outside our system executes the action of wanting to "create a book". I like the last alternative, but do not really know if it follows best-practices and is scalable.

You should put the logic you described (creating a book and sending an email) into one use case. And you should not have use cases that use other use cases, instead you should reuse entities in different use cases.

As Robert Martin writes in his article The Clean Architecture.

The Dependency Rule: ... source code dependencies can only point
inwards.
Use Cases: ... use cases orchestrate the flow of data to and from the entities...


Conceptually, your use case might look something like this:
class CreateBookUseCase {
    private final Clients clients;
    private final MailServer mailServer;

    CreateBookUseCase(Clients clients, MailServer mailServer) {
        this.clients = clients;
        this.mailServer = mailServer;
    }

    void createBook(String clientId, BookData bookData) {
        Books clientBooks = clients.client(clientId).books();
        clientBooks.add(/* book */);
        if (clientBooks.amount() == 1) {
            mailServer.send(/* email */);
        }
    }
}


yeah this is how I have done it previously. But then I read some that uses use-cases like services and basically call them from other use-cases. But I feel like that kind of destroys the meaning of the word use-case. I seems that generally the word use-case is used differently by different developers

@OdinHufnagl You specified the tag "clean architecture", I gave you an article by the author of this concept, where he explains the concept of a use case and gives the main principle regarding the direction of dependencies. If you call use cases from use cases, you can potentially get cyclic dependencies.

I agree with this answer. If you treat uses cases as discrete 'vertical' slices, that stay in their lane and do not take dependencies on other use cases, you'll have much better isolation that should give you software that's easier to reason about, enhance and maintain.
